# I/O error on dm-3 but I am not using LVM

Tags: lvm

I've got these errors, but I don't know what partition/disk corresponds to dm3 or even dm-3-8.

> [22083.266714] Buffer I/O error on dev **dm-3**, logical block 33062912,
>   lost sync page write [22083.266727] JBD2: Error -5 detected when
>   updating journal superblock for dm-3-8. [22083.266729] Aborting
>   journal on device **dm-3-8**. [22083.266847] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-3,
>   logical block 33062912, lost sync page write [22083.266855] JBD2:
>   Error -5 detected when updating journal superblock for dm-3-8.
>   [22083.267357] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-3, logical block 0, lost
>   sync page write [22083.267368] EXT4-fs (dm-3): I/O error while writing
>   superblock

How I know which partition corresponds to dm-3?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dmsetup` to list dependencies of dm-3:

```
dmsetup deps -o devname /dev/dm-3
```

or, to show a list of all device mapper devices and its dependent devices:

```
dmsetup ls --tree -o blkdevname
```